# React JS (JSX) что значит два двоеточия перед this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es2016, es7

Компонент содержит такую строку

```
onSubmit={::this.onAddKey}
```

Какое значение она несет в себе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это синтаксический сахар из **ES7** для `bind`:
`::this.onAddKey` то же самое, что и  `this.onAddKey = this.onAddKey.bind(this)`

ES7:

```
// Binding a function to a context
let log = ::console.log;

// Calling functions with a context
let foo = {};

function bar() {
  log(this);
}

function world(a) {
  log(this, a);
}

foo::bar();

function hello() {
  foo::world(...arguments);
}
```

ES5:

```
// Binding a function to a context
var log = console.log.bind(console);

// Calling functions with a context
var foo = {};

function bar() {
  log(this);
}

function world(a) {
  log(this, a);
}

bar.call(foo);

function hello() {
  world.apply(foo, arguments);
}
```

https://blog.jeremyfairbank.com/javascript/javascript-es7-function-bind-syntax/

Comment: `ES7` Или `ES2017`

Comment: ES7 <==> ES2016